# Android returns null when i read GPS location

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read the position of my android device using this code but it returns null on longitude and latitude, although I added the right permission and I tried it on my android device while the GPS is enabled. I tried to figure out the problem and find out that this if statement is not true

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

and I tried to change the != to == it didn't work also ,and if I tried to delete this if statement , it gives me error:
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`
this is my GPS code:

```
public class GPSPosition extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 100 * 60*1; // 60 seconds

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSPosition(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("enabless1", "Network");
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }




    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //  Toast.makeText(mContext, "log:" + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) + ", lat: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

here I call them in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String lat="10";
    public static String lang="10";
    GPSPosition gps;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lat + " " + lang, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        gps = new GPSPosition(MainActivity.this);

    }

    public void clickingBtn(View view) {



        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            lang = String.valueOf(longitude);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, latitude + " " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    }
```

this is the permissions in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` will return `null` if there is no recent location data for that provider. And, even if it returns something other than `null`, the `Location` might be fairly old. In cases where `getLastKnownLocation()` returns something unusable, you will have to wait until `onLocationChanged()` is called, then use the `Location` passed into that method.

Comment: but it never give back any value and even it never continue in code , I put some log code to see if it runs that code , but it didn't and i don't know why

Comment: @SalehRefaai: "it never give back any value" -- I do not know what "it" is. "it never continue in code" -- I do not know what "it" is. "to see if it runs" -- I do not know what "it" is. " but it didn't" -- I do not know what "it" is.

Comment: @SalehRefaai: [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v7.6/Internet/Weather) demonstrating the use of `LocationManager`. It has a `targetSdkVersion` of 17, so it does not demonstrate the use of runtime permissions. Also, it may not be able to retrieve a weather forecast for non-US locations.